# GCP: Connect cloud & Cloud SQL, running in two different projects

Tags: google-cloud-platform, connection, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run

Currently we are trying to access Cloud SQL from Cloud Run via private IPs. The Cloud Run and Cloud SQL instances are in separate projects. Once the two VPCs are peered, VMs between the projects can ping each other and connectivity is established. But the Cloud Run instance cannot connect with the Cloud SQL using private IPs. I understand the Cloud SQL is in it's own private services access connection. without using Shared VPC and cloud sql proxy

created the firewall rules, vpc peering done,

Comment: It's expected, you can't connect to Cloud SQL because of the limitations on VPC peering. Basically Cloud SQL is lives in a another project (service project) and the way it connects is using a VPC peering. Since you're trying to connect using another peering, the connection won't work because peering are not transitive. Read https://stackoverflow.com/a/62521730/12265927

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GCP: connect to CloudSQL instances via peering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62520232/gcp-connect-to-cloudsql-instances-via-peering)

Comment: Create a Serverless VPC Access connector in the same VPC network as your Cloud SQL instance. Configure Cloud Run to use the connector.

Comment: @JohnHanley's comment is probably the answer.